Four Minim blessing with a lack of one Hadas myrtle
The one who blessed the 4 Minim and found out (retrospectively after the blessing) that one myrtle cloth fell on him on the way and blessed the set with only two myrtle instead of 3. Before the shaking of the blessing he discovered this and added the myrtle. Is it necessary to repeat the blessing or did it come out with a blessing?

This basically happened once to Rabbenu Meshullam. One year he accidentally forgot to put the Aravot in his Lulav-bundle and he only noticed after already shaking the deficient bundle and doing something else. He went and put the Aravot back in and blessed "Al Netilat Arava" (and Shehechiyanu since it was the first day) and shook the whole bundle again. His reasoning was the four species can in principle be taken sequentially instead of all together (Menachot 27a) so he only needs to bless on the remaining species, but it is better to take them all together so he picked them up together. (The story is quoted in Orchot Chaim (Lulav 22), in the Beit Yosef (651), and many later authorities.)
Accordingly in your case, if you hadn't interrupted yet after blessing you can just pick up and add the missing myrtle branch, but if you did interrupt then the initial blessing can't cover the myrtle and you'd pick up the three myrtle branches (and ideally all the other species too) and bless "Al Netilat Hadas" (and Shehechiyanu on the first day).
However, this assumes you actually need all 3 myrtle branches. That's a dispute in the Mishna (Sukkah 3:4) and while most authorities rule like the position that you need 3, Ramban rules you can suffice with 1 myrtle branch (cf. OC 651:1). Accordingly, if only one of the three myrtle branches was missing, you may have already fulfilled your obligation and should probably omit any further blessings out of doubt (especially since some later authorities question Rabbeinu Meshullam's position entirely).

According to Rabbi Akiva's method, halachically, there is a need for only one Hadas and one Arava.

@Avi yes that is correct

Just a few notes on this rare case, that some question if R Meshullam actually said a new blessing on the arava and maybe just said shehechiyanu, some suggest the blessing for myrtles should be "Al Netilat Eitz Avot" but it is a mystery why only here would we use the biblical language, and finally that you have to have owned the missing species the whole time or else sequential taking doesn't work and you have to start over with the Lulav. Also note Tosafot doesn't think sequential taking works at all.

Even if all the minim were held at the same time, right side up, he has still not fulfilled the mitzva as it should be done, as is brought in Mishna berura 651:4

וג' הדסים - אפילו שלשתן קטומים שנקטמו ראשן ופחות משלשה לא מהני אפילו לא היו קטומים
And three myrtles - even if all three are cut, that their tops were cut; but less than three is not helpful (meaning, the mtizva isn't considered fulfilled), even if they were not cut.

Therefore, it seems like one would need to retake the 4 minim to fulfill the mitzva. However, there is still the question regarding the bracha (assuming the previous bracha wouldn't work for this time, because of a hefsek - a break - between the bracha and the current taking of the minim). As was pointed out to me in the comments, the shulchan aruch goes on to say that if one doesn't have three hadassim, he should shake with one, which seems to say that bediavad one hadas is enough.
The Kaf Hachayim there (seif katan 4) talks about this explicitly:

נטלו כל הקהל ולא היה בלולב אלא ב' הדסים, צריך לחזור וליטול לולב בג' הדסים ואין כאן משום מוקצה אך לא יברכו
If the entire congregation took [the 4 minim] and there were only two myrtles, they must retake the minim with three myrtles, and there is no problem of Muktze, but they should not make a bracha

(He quotes this in the name of the Beis david, birkei yosef, knesses hagdola, and shaarei teshuva)

Interestingly, the Kaf Hachayim goes on to talk about if someone was missing one of his Aravos, in which case he brings an opinion which says he should make another bracha, because having two Aravos is learned from the Torah. He still seems to lean towards not making a bracha, though.

Fixed the answer, @JoelK (and whoever else saw, and very fairly downvoted).

Those would likely be Kneset Hagedola, responsa Beit David, Birkei Yosef, and Shaarei Teshuva
